# How to add image from database to PictureBox?

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox

I am using this to get image bytes from the database

```
cmd.CommandText = "select imagedate from projectimages where imagename = '" + _
    ListBox1.Text + "' and CSVprojectref=checksum('" + textboxFileRef.Text + "')"

Dim img As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Now how can I add this to PictureBox.image.  I am having a lot of trouble retrieving the image and displaying it in the PictureBox.

The datatype is Image in sql database and i use this code to save image to db

```
         Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream

        If imageFilename.Contains("jpeg") Or imageFilename.Contains("jpg") Then
            imageUpload.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        End If
        If imageFilename.Contains("png") Then
            imageUpload.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        End If
        If imageFilename.Contains("gif") Then
            imageUpload.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
        End If
        If imageFilename.Contains("bmp") Then
            imageUpload.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End If

        Dim bytes() As Byte = ms.ToArray
        Dim img As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)


        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert projectimages values('" + imageNameTemp + "','" + img + "',CHECKSUM('" + textboxFileRef.Text + "'))", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: What version of VB are you using?

Comment: OK, you should get more people looking now.

Comment: i found the perfect solution after searching for hours there is a specific way to store data so it is retrieved perfectly. Will post the answer tomorrow as i cannot post answer to my own question before 8 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 5-6 hours of searching  forums and blogs and everything i fond this... to save image to database

1- datatype should be image in database

Now add this code when storing image to the sql database

```
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    imageFilename = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim imageUpload As Image
    imageUpload = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)



    If imageFilename <> "" Then

        Dim imageNameTemp As String

        imageNameTemp = imageFilename

        While (imageNameTemp.Contains("\"))


            imageNameTemp = imageNameTemp.Remove(0, imageNameTemp.IndexOf("\") + 1)
        End While

        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream

        If imageFilename.Contains("jpeg") Or imageFilename.Contains("jpg") Then
            imageUpload.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        End If
        If imageFilename.Contains("png") Then
            imageUpload.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        End If
        If imageFilename.Contains("gif") Then
            imageUpload.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
        End If
        If imageFilename.Contains("bmp") Then
            imageUpload.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End If

        'Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO projectimages (imagename,imagedate,csvprojectref) VALUES ('" + imageFilename + "',@BLOBData,CHECKSUM('" + textboxFileRef.Text + "'))", con)

        Dim b() As Byte = ms.ToArray()

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO projectimages (imagename,imagedate,csvprojectref) VALUES ('" + imageNameTemp + "',@BLOBData,CHECKSUM('" + textboxFileRef.Text + "'))", con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BLOBData", SqlDbType.Image, b.Length).Value = b
        '    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert projectimages(imagename,imagedate,csvprojectref) values('imagma','" + img + "',CHECKSUM('" + textboxFileRef.Text + "'))", con)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        '  cmdTemp.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image, b.Length).Value = b

    End If
```

And when to retrieve data to insert into picture box  use this code...

```
  cmd.CommandText = "select imagedate from projectimages where imagename = '" +      ListBox1.Text + "' and CSVprojectref=checksum('" + textboxFileRef.Text + "')"


        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "projectimages")
        Dim c As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        If c > 0 Then
            Dim bytBLOBData() As Byte = _
                ds.Tables(0).Rows(c - 1)("imagedate")
            Dim stmBLOBData As New MemoryStream(bytBLOBData)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData)
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a MemoryStream object as per [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317670).

Comment: same error comes on the line... as above "paramater in not valid "

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim img As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
Dim ms as MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(img)
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

assuming imagedate field a `blob` field.

Comment: this error Parameter is not valid.

on 
       PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(MemoryStreamms)

Comment: @ConfusedCoder it has to be `Dim ms as MemoryStream`. see if that fixes the error.

Comment: i m fighting with this for last 2 hours or more :(

Comment: btw what do u mean by  imagedate field a blob field?

Comment: @Con, have you verified that ExecuteScalar() is actually getting the picture?

Comment: see info on [blob here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object). But it doesn't look like that's your problem. Maybe the image isn't formatted right or corrupt in the database?

Comment: yes i get the same byte length when i store the image so it gets everything back from db

Answer (score 0):

here's my code to show blob file to picturebox in vb.net. hope it helps

```
Dim connstring As String = "Database=pmk;data source=localhost;user id=root;password="
Dim Sql As String = "select * from mastermahasiswa where Nim='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn)
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
conn.Open()
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
dr.Read()
Dim imagebytes As Byte() = CType(dr("Foto"), Byte())
Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(imagebytes)
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Using
conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the parameter not valid error as well.  To fix, I added a picturebox to my form that loads the image I'm copying to the SQL server as a background image.  This statement seems to be key:

```
PictureBox1.BackgroundImage.Save(ms, PictureBox1.BackgroundImage.RawFormat)
```

It makes the actual upload take a lot longer, but I'm no longer getting the parameter error... I think because the pictures are actually valid images now.

```
        SSScmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PreviewSlideshow (Name, Photo) VALUES (@name, @photo)"

        Dim p As New SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.Image)

        For Each CurFile As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(sSourcePath).GetFiles

            If CurFile.Name = "Thumbs.db" Then
                'skip
            Else

                If CurFile.Extension = "jpg" Or CurFile.Extension = "png" Then

                    'show the image name on the form
                    ImageName.Text = CurFile.Name

                    SSScmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ImageName.Text)

                    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()

                    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(sSourcePath & CurFile.Name)

                    PictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch

                    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage.Save(ms, PictureBox1.BackgroundImage.RawFormat)

                    Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()

                    p.Value = data

                    SSScmd.Parameters.Add(p)

                    SSScmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    SSScmd.Parameters.Clear()



                End If
            End If

        Next
```